# How to apply a function on pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have a pandas dataframe like this, with `user_id`, `title` of the song listened by the user and the number of times that a specific user has listened to that song (`listen_count`).

[image]

#### Goal to achieve:

I'm new to python and pandas and I'm trying to build a recommender system. I want to transform these *implicit feedbacks* (`listen_count`) into *explicit* ones following the **(8)** and **(9)** formulas of [this](https://mpacula.com/publications/lastfm.pdf) paper.

- To do this I want to create a function that compute the **listening frequency for each song by each user** in the dataframe, using this formula:
  [image]
  where **count(i,j)** stands for the number of times a certain user has played a certain song (the `listen_count` value in my dataframe), divided by the total number of plays made by the user on all songs listened by him (the `total listen_count` for each user)
- I also want to create a function that implements the formula (9) of the above mentioned paper, but I think it will be simpler if someone can explain me how to solve the previous problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this problem by using `DataFrame.groupby()`. Assuming that your dataframe is called `df`, you can try the following(it's hard for me to check if it produces the right result without the data).

```
# get the total listen count for each user_id
df['total_listen_count_per_user'] = df.groupby('user_id')['listen_count'].transform('sum')
# get the song frequency by dividing the sum of song_listen_counts per song by
# the total_listen_count for each user
df['song_frequency']=df.groupby('title')['listen_count'].transform('sum')/df['total_listen_count_per_user']
```

Here is the reference for [DataFrame.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem regards the computation of the frequency of the songs listened by every user. What I want is for example: my user has listened songs A, B and C --> For this user the listen frequency is: freq(A) = listening_of_A/(listening of A+ B + C), freq(B) = listening_of_B/(listening of A+ B+ C).. and I want this for every song that every user has listened to